# OpenGL C# ball emitter

Tags: c#, opengl

I am trying to make my opengl program emit balls from a cube. There are two types of balls - a small blue one and a larger orange one. The balls should fall due to gravity. However at the moment it only seems to emit one of each ball and thats it.

I have tried drawing the balls inside a loop, as follows:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < 100; i = i + 1)
        {
            Matrix4 mSphereOrange = Matrix4.CreateScale(mOrangeRadius) * Matrix4.CreateTranslation(mOrangePosition);

            SetUniformVariables(0.19125f, 0.0735f, 0.054f, 1, 0.647f, 0f, 0.256777f, 0.137622f, 0.086014f, 0.5f);
            GL.UniformMatrix4(uModelLocation, true, ref mSphereOrange);
            GL.BindVertexArray(mVAO_IDs[2]);
            GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, mSphereModelUtility.Indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);

            Matrix4 mSphereBlue = Matrix4.CreateScale(mBlueRadius) * Matrix4.CreateTranslation(mBluePosition);

            SetUniformVariables(0, 0.1f, 0.06f, 0.0f, 0.50980392f, 0.50980392f, 0.50196078f, 0.50196078f, 0.50196078f, 10f);
            GL.UniformMatrix4(uModelLocation, true, ref mSphereBlue);
            GL.BindVertexArray(mVAO_IDs[2]);
            GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, mSphereModelUtility.Indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);


        }
```

Can anyone see why this may not be working? Or suggest a better way to create an emitter?

Any help would be much appreciated,
Lucy

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that the problem is related with for loop. You create simultaneously 100 orange spheres and 100 blue spheres at the same position.

Comment: ah okay, do you think that they are just drawing on top of each other? I thought that because the balls instantly begin falling you would see the others, but i am probably wrong.

Comment: Yes, the balls are drawn on top each other. Involve the "i" to change the position of each ball or apply a different force or draw a ball on some time interval not at once.